# Reflection of waves on the basis of particle theory

Tags: photons, reflection

As it is an established fact now that light shows dual nature, can we explain the phenomena of reflection of light considering it to be particle.

If it can be done, then I have a question:

> How can we explain the law of reflection, i.e., angle of incidence = angle of reflection, when we consider a photon to be colliding with a surface and reflecting back?

Comment: The behavior of photons is treated by Quantum Electrodynamics (QED). Here is a video based on the model used by Feynman's in his book on QED. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1GdgD77AQ4&list=PL5D42C612A47C09FB&index=7&t=857s